# DotNetBrowser is not rendering print accordingly on Chrome

Tags: c#, chromium, dotnetbrowser

I have an `WebApi` that needs to generate some PDF based on the data that some customer filled in and send back to him by e-mail (on a beautiful pdf form).

We decided to use `DotNetBrowser` to do it. Once everything was already made in HTML. We developed our form using Chrome to check and see how the things were going.

On Chrome it's ok, we can save the PDF exactly as we want, but when the server calls the DNB to generate the PDF, some strange things happens.
We loose control of the footer and some text overlaps other text. It mess up all the page.
I'm using some example that implements a `PDFHandler` to save the PDF.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After getting some tips with the support team of DNB, we figureout that our DLL (that contains the built-in chromiun) was in a wrong version. We updated the DLL downloading the newest from DNB website and everything was ok.
We learned that we need to use the Chromiun executable to create and debug our page, so it will be nice when running on DNB.
Thanks for the support team!